# how to define generic variables in Python (syntax question)

Tags: python

With Python it is easy to declare something like

```
self.x = "something"
print self.x #outputs "something"
```

I want to have something like this:

```
param["key"] = "x"
self.param["key"] = "something" #here I actually want to access this "self" parameter as below with its value defined above
print self.x #supposed to output "something" as well. Note that "x" refers to value defined in the first line
```

Is there any such thing? Is there any similar alternatives?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's really hard to understand, what you are trying to achieve. Could you be a bit clearer?

Comment: you are right, it was hard to explain as well. I can just tell, I wanted to achieve something like the answer below

Comment: The question makes much more sense once you see the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`setattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr) -- `setattr(self, param['key'], 'something')`.